# Uncaught ReferenceError: Grid is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to set up https://github.com/codrops/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview in WordPress.

The problem I am facing is:

[image]

Here's the code in the init file. Any ideas?

```
jQuery(function($){

    Grid.init();

});
```

I had to wrap the code in grid.js between `(function($) {` and `})(jQuery);` to get rid of:

[image]

This is how I am loading the js files:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sk_enqueue_scripts' );
function sk_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.custom.js', '', '1.0.0', false );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'grid', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/grid.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'grid-init', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/grid-init.js', array( 'grid' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems JQuery library is not loaded in the file before grid.js? Please check

Comment: It is. jquery.js is being loaded in the header. grid.js and grid-init.js are being loaded in the footer in that order.

Comment: Try loading the init code in a `<script>Grid.init();</script>` tag, you may have a scoping issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just add var $ = jQuery; at the top of the grid.js file and that should fix it.

Comment: More elaboration is needed here. Please consider adding an explanation as to why he should do this, or maybe why `jQuery` may not be aliased to `$` - the OP already has a solution that does exactly the same thing (but doesn't pollute the global namespace, btw)

Comment: This fixed the issue.